# Cannot add dynamic bootstrap select to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to add a `bootstrap-select` dynamically in a table defined as follow:

```
<table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Select</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Gmail</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" id="select0">
                                    <option>opt1</option>
                                     <option>opt2</option>
                                    </select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="mail" name="mail" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Essentially my script create new row to that table when the user press a button.
The problem is that the new `bootstrap-select` which you can download [here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/), is not added correctly, infact is invisible. I don't know how to fix that, some one could help me?

This is the js code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $("#addrow").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><select class="selectpicker" id="select' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone' + counter + '"/></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
  });



   $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1
   });


    });
```

and [this is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jorbuv0f/).

Comment: You're going to have to initialize the widget on all new elements that it should be initialized on.

Comment: @Taplar I added the class `selectpicker` which do this automatically, but on dynamic item not

Comment: There isn't anything automatic about it.  The library on page load may auto initialize elements with the class, but that is only on page load.  Which is why you have to manually initialize any you create after the fact.  The plugin isn't going to poll your page to look for elements that get that class, or are created with that class.

Comment: @Taplar ok, I tried with: `$('#select'+counter).selectpicker();` and still didn't work

Comment: `$('select').selectpicker();` on the last line of your on click function will create a new select list if you test it on your fiddle. You still need to build the options though. Might be easier to just clone a select element that is the "master template" so to speak. https://jsfiddle.net/swry4okq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure what you meant by `$(...).selectpicker()` didn't work, because I tested it in your fiddle and it worked just fine. I forked it here https://jsfiddle.net/hpysz5xr/

The code is included below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $("#addrow").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><select class="selectpicker" id="select' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone' + counter + '"/></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    $('#select'+counter).selectpicker();
    counter++;
  });



  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Select</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Gmail</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" id="criteria0">
          <option>opt1</option>
          <option>opt2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="mail" name="mail" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-2">
        <a class="deleteRow"></a>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```